# How to inject a Map<String, List> in java springs?

Tags: java, spring

How to inject a Map in java spring framework?
If possible please provide some sample code.

Is the following legal?

```xml
<property name="testMap">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <value>test</value>
            </key>
            <value>
                <list>
                    <value>String</value>
                    <value>String</value>
                </list>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </map> 
</property>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Define a Map like this first inside your `applicationContext.xml`:

```xml
<util:list id="list1">
    <value>foo@bar.com</value>
    <value>foo1@bar.com</value>
</util:list>

<util:list id="list2">
    <value>foo2@bar.com</value>
    <value>foo3@bar.com</value>
</util:list>

<util:map id="emailMap" value-type="java.util.List">
    <!-- Map between String key and List -->
    <entry key="entry1" value-ref="list1" />
    <entry key="entry2" value-ref="list2" />
    ...
</util:map>
```

Then use this Map in any bean of yours like this:

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="com.sample.beans">
    <property name="emailMap" ref="emailMap" />
</bean>
```

Comment: how to do this in .properties file?

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979119/548225

Answer (score 26):

I think your syntax is not legal as spring throws `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` when processing the bean configuration xml .

It should work after removing the `<value>` tag around the  `<list>`.

```xml
<property name="testMap">
    <map>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <value>test</value>
            </key>

             <list>
                    <value>String</value>
                    <value>String</value>
             </list>
        </entry>
    </map> 
</property>
```

Answer (score 7):

This is my example:

```xml
<bean class="com.common.handlermgmnt.HandlerMapAdder">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.util.Map">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.common.ViewWidget">
            <entry key="DefaultView">
                <bean class="com.common.DefaultViewWidget"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="AnotherView">
                <bean class="com.common.AnotherViewWidget"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="com.common.handlermgmnt.HandlerManager" ref="widget_handlerManager"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inject it using SpEL. #{id}. this works for me.

in the .xml:

```xml
<util:map id="roleLocationMap">
    <entry key="ROLE_ADMIN" value-ref="listA" />
    <entry key="ROLE_USER" value-ref="listB" />
</util:map>
```

in the .java

```
@Autowired
public MainController(
        @Value("#{roleLocationMap}") final Map<String, List<String>> roleLocationMap) {
    this.roleLocationMap = roleLocationMap;
}
```

Comment: how to do this in .properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this case myself.  If no need to reuse the list values as independent beans elsewhere, you could use this shorter version, without using 'value-ref':

```xml
<util:map id="mymap">
    <entry key="key1">
        <util:list>
            <value>val1</value>
            <value>val2</value>
        </util:list>
    </entry>
    <entry key="key2">
        <util:list>
            <value>val2</value>
            <value>val3</value>
            <value>val4</value>
        </util:list>
    </entry>
</util:map>
```

And, wire it up in your Java code like this:

```
@Resource(name="mymap")
Map<String, List<String>> mapKey_List;
```