# how to load map from properties file with spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to load a map from .properties file into a `HashMap`

the properties file has the following:

```
try.map= one=1,\
two=2
```

The code:

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${try.map}")
HashMap<String, String> tryMap;
```

And loading the property to the map results in :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.HashMap]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any ideas how to create a mapping strategy for this?

Comment: You have yout own converter and add it to the coversationService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default converter for that. So you have to write your own converter and register it to the conversationService.

Here an annotation-based example:

```
@Bean(name="conversionService") 
public static ConversionService getConversionService(){
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter<?,?>> converters = new HashSet<Converter<?,?>>();
    converters.add(new StringToHashMapConverter());
    conversionServiceFactoryBean.setConverters(converters);
    conversionServiceFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return conversionServiceFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

The Converter:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class StringToHashMapConverter implements Converter<String,HashMap> {

    @Override
    public HashMap convert(String paramS) {
           //do the coversion
    }

}
```

Comment: @Gleeb can you explain why?

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have a conversation service in my app.  I will update the question with its confirmation maybe it's not configured properly

Comment: Can you try to debug your code if the Converter is called? Please check if you are using annotation configuration in your project.

Comment: ok, this works but there is a problem where in some places some configuration files are loaded before the conversion service bean, how do i guarantee that the conversion service is loaded before any other bean?

Comment: I think spring will load the converter before the beans are created. So you can not have such situation. If you have the Problem you can use the `@DependsOn` annotation to guarantee that the conversation service is loaded before the bean. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

i got this error too. If you want to resolve it without doing much efforts, just check your imports properly.
Mostly you will get this error if you import wrong files. In case of you, I think you are importing wrong HashMap in your file. Check it should be java.util.HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
try.map= {\
  one: 1,\
  two: 2\
}
```

The code:

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("#{${try.map}}")
HashMap<String, String> tryMap;
```

Yes, the syntax is quite odd.

This SO post has more info:
[How to fill HashMap from java property file with Spring @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value)