# Populating a HashMap with entries from a properties file for @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have properties file which has a key `company.id` like this

```
company.id=key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value4
```

Now, I want to store key-value pair directly in map using @Value of spring

```
//For example,
//for key in properties file
//company.list=comp1,comp2
@Value("#{'${proposal.provience}'.split(',')}")
List<String> companyList;
the above will directly converts to List.
```

Please tell me what to write here without using other libraries like Guava

```
@value(some logic here)
HashMap<String,String> map;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill HashMap from java property file with Spring @Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value)

Comment: @NamanGala But i need to add another library as they are using PropertyMapper in @ Value

Comment: You could use a @Value annotated setter and process the value in there?

Comment: @PeterK thnaks for the answer.Thats what i'm doing now.