# How to read property file values into set of Strings in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, properties-file

I have tried using

```
@Value("#{'${white.listed.hotel.ids}'.split(',')}")
private Set<String> fareAlertwhiteListedHotelIds;
```

but When *white.listed.hotel.ids* is empty then also set has one size with blank value.

> white.listed.hotel.ids =

Can someone pls help me with a version in which ***whiteListedHotelIds*** can contain either values if specified in property file or has no item for blank case.

Comment: do you mean specifying a default value in case whiteListedHotelIds is empty ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991194/can-i-set-null-as-the-default-value-for-a-value-in-spring

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte van houtte : I just wanted the set to be Empty in case whiteListedHotelIds  is Empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call a custom method ([as described in this other answer to build a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510354/spring-boot-configurationproperties-yaml-referencing/39552824#39552824), itself inspired by [@FedericoPeraltaSchaffner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value/28370899#28370899)):

```
@Value("#{PropertySplitter.toSet('${white.listed.hotel.ids}')}")
private Set<String> fareAlertwhiteListedHotelIds;

...

@Component("PropertySplitter")
public class PropertySplitter {
    public Set<String> toSet(String property) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

        //not sure if you should trim() or not, you decide.
        if(!property.trim().isEmpty()){
            Collections.addAll(set, property.split(","));
        }

        return set;
    }
}
```

In this method, you are free to handle the property as you wish (for instance a particular logic when empty).

Comment: Or `Collections.addAll(set, property.split(","));` skipping the intermediate `List` step.

Comment: Thanks @Holger! I've replaced Arrays.asList(...) with your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spring expression language for validation as well, if the provided string is empty then return empty array or split input string into array. From jdk-11 you can use [isBlank](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) directly

```
@Value("#{'${white.listed.hotel.ids}'.trim().isEmpty() ? new String[] {} : '${white.listed.hotel.ids}'.split(',')}")
private Set<String> fareAlertwhiteListedHotelIds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject `@Value` through constructor (as you always should) and do all post-processing you need there:

```
@Component
class Foo {
    private final List<String> bar;

    public Foo(@Value("${foo.bar}") List<String> bar) {
        this.bar = bar.stream()
                      .filter(s -> !"".equals(s))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

There is no need to complicate things with SPEL.