# Get values into a map using spring el

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, properties-file, spring-el

I have a value in a properties file that goes

```
currency.codes=US:USD,IN:INR,AU:AUD
```

I am looking to get these values into a map with a (key,value) pair like (US,USD) etc using spring el
I'm trying something like

```
@Value("#{'${currency.codes}'.split(',|:')}")
    private Map<String, String> myMap;
```

This obviously doesn't work. But I would be grateful if anyone can suggest me with such minimal code or any other alternate solution.
There are a lot of properties like this that I need to get into maps.
-TIA

Comment: You may find your answer here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value

Answer (score 1):

You can write a static helper method and [use that in your expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) to reduce the complexity of the SpEL code.

```
public class MapDecoder {
    public static Map<String, String> decodeMap(String value) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String[] pairs = value.split(",");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            String[] parts = pair.split(":");
            map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        return map;
    }
}

public class MyBean {
    @Value("#{T(mypackage.MapDecoder).decodeMap('${currency.codes}')}")
    private Map<String, String> myMap;
}
```