# Spring Boot - inject map from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

property file looks like this:

```
url1=path_to_binary1
url2=path_to_binary2
```

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540254/2674303) I tried following approach:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private Map<String, String> pathMapper;

    //get and set
}
```

and in another component I autowired ApplicationProperties:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationProperties properties;         
      //inside some method:
      properties.getPathMapper().get(appName);
```

produces `NullPointerException`.

How to correct it?

### update

I have correct according user7757360 advice:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
public class ApplicationProperties {
```

and properties file:

```
app.url1=path_to_binary1
app.url2=path_to_binary2
```

Still doesn't work

### Update 2

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private Map<String, String> app;
```

and inside `application.properties`:

```
app.url1=path_to_binary1
app.url2=path_to_binary2
```

Still doesn't work

Comment: You can find a better answer here: [How to fill HashMap from java property file with Spring @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NullPointerException` is probably from empty `ApplicationProperties`.

All custom properties should be annotated `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="custom")`. 
After that, on your main class (class with main method) you must add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CustomProperties.class)`. 
For autocomplete you can use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

If you use `@ConfigurationProperties` without prefix you use only field name. Field name in you properites. In your case `path-mapper`, next you specific `key` and `value`. Example:

```
path-mapper.key=value
```

Remeber after changes in your own properites you need to reload application. Example:

https://github.com/kchrusciel/SpringPropertiesExample

Comment: What the prefix ?

Comment: You can use prefix custom.pathMapper.value=my value, or @ConfigurationProperties("") for pathMapper.value=my value. This values need to be added in application.properties.

Comment: please read topic update. Looks another answer same with your advice

Comment: You use app.url1=path_to_binary1 but variable name is pathMapper

Comment: How should I use it?

Comment: path-mapper.value=10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139390/discussion-between-kchrusciel-and-gstackoverflow).

Comment: prefix and field name should be same?

Comment: Can you provide precise answer in you answer?

Comment: If you use @ConfigurationProperties without prefix. You should use: field-name.key = value (key and value like in the map)

Comment: can you extend it for map with several values?

Comment: Updated github.com/kchrusciel/SpringPropertiesExample

Answer (score 7):

it would be helpful if you can give a more specific example for property file. You should have the same prefix in the url1 and url2 and then you can use

`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")`

as in

`my.pathMapper.url1=path_to_binary1
my.pathMapper.url2=path_to_binary2`

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private Map<String, String> pathMapper;

    //get and set for pathMapper are important
}
```

see more at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

Comment: Where to write properties file name?

Comment: based your update your properties file should be ```app.app.url1=path_to_binary1
app.app.url2=path_to_binary2```  I recommend using  a different prefix

Comment: assuming you use defaults, spring-boot looks for the default name ``application.properties``  so there is no need to write the properties file name anywhere.  Just ensure ``application.properties`` is in ``src/main/resources`` as shown in the example provided by @kchrusciel

Answer (score 1):

There are two things need you need to feed map from properties file. First you need to have a class which has the configuration and target fields to hold data from properties file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:myprops.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("props")
@Component
public class Properties{
   private Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
   // getter setter
}
```

Secondly define the properties file named myprops.properties with all properties as props

```
props.map.port = 443
props.map.active = true
props.map.user = aUser
```

Comment: It does not allow you to have `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Component` or `@Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Have the your.properties file under `src/main/resources` and either have it as a

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:your.properties")
public class SpringConfig(){}
```

or have it as a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in your Spring `yourApplicationContext.xml`.

Then use the property values like

```
@Value("app.url1")
String path_to_binary1;

@Value("app.url2")
String path_to_binary2;

// ...

System.out.println(path_to_binary1+path_to_binary2);
```