# Spring Boot - Injecting a map from a YAML file

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, kotlin, yaml

I tried several versions but none work.
What's the correct way to have this injected as a map:

**application.yml**

```
alias:
  name: title
  desc: description
  content: body
```

I tried using `@Value` annotation:

**NamingService.kt**

```
@Value("\${alias}")
private var alias: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()
```

I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'alias' in value "${alias}"
```

*kotlinVersion = '1.2.31'; springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'*

Comment: same issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098009/spring-boot-inject-map-from-properties-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have something similar in our code. This is how we solved it.

**application.yml**

```
validation:
  synonyms:
    Doctor: Dr.
    Sanct: St.
```

**Config**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("validation")
public class ValidationConfig {

    private Map<String, String> synonyms;
    // ...
}
```

You can find more information for this topic in the documentation: [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)