# Spring. Load complete properties file in class field as map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

it should be easy. But I have not some idea. A file 'props.properties' on disk. Where are any properties in the file. I have a class of configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:props.properties", encoding = "utf8")
public class AppConfig {
...
  @Some_spring_annotation  <-- that is qestion
  private Map map;
...
}
```

How to load all properties from 'props.properties' to 'map' by Spring?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691949/how-to-inject-a-map-using-the-value-spring-annotation

Use annotation @Value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - inject map from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098009/spring-boot-inject-map-from-properties-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load whole porperties file as Map by defining it as PropertiesFactoryBean and then using it with @Resource annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:src/main/resources/test.properties", encoding = "utf8")
public class AppConfig {

@Value("${propertyname}")
String prop;

@Resource(name = "propertyBean")
private Map<String, String> propMap;

@Bean(name = "propertyBean")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/test.properties"));
        return bean;
}

public Map<String, String> getPropMap() {
    return propMap;
}
}
```

And access any key present in the properties file using key like below:-

```
@RestController
public class Test {

@Autowired
private AppConfig appConfig;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String  login(HttpServletRequest request){
    return appConfig.getPropMap().get("application.name");
}

}



test.propeties:-
server.port1=8099
application.name=edge-service
propertyname=dddd
```

In this you don't need to write @Value annotation everytime, you can access values using 
propMap. If you want to read single key use

```
@Value("${propertyname}")
String prop;
```

Even you can define map data into property file

```
propertyname={key1:'value1',key2:'value2'}
```

There can be many implementation to achieve it based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Properties file entry

```
valMap ={key1: '1', key2: '2', key3: '3'}
```

Spring annotation

```
@Value("#{${valMap}}")
private Map<String, Integer> valMap;
```

More on @Value annotation here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Answer (score 0):

You can have values from properties file read in a single `map`

Your `application.properties` file should look like

```java
app.properties.map.key1 = value1
app.properties.map.key2 = value2
app.properties.map.key3 = value3
app.properties.map.key4 = value4
app.properties.map.key5 = value5
```

And, your `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class should look like

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.properties")
public class AppProperties {

    private Map<String, String> map;

    // No Arguments Constructor

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

***Also, starting from [Spring Boot 2.2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes), your `@ConfigurationProperties` classes can be immutable***

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.properties")
public class AppProperties {

    private final Map<String, String> map;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public AppProperties(Map<String, String> map) {

      this.map = map;
    }
}
```