# Loading Map<String List<String>> from properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, collections, properties-file

I'm working on a spring application where I need to get a Map from the property file.
The sample Java code is

```
public static final Map<String, List<String>> txn = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, List<String>>(){{
    put("DIV",Arrays.asList("AA","CD","DD","EF"));
    put("TFER", Arrays.asList("J","TE","EF","RE"));
    put("PPO", Arrays.asList("PPIN","PPOUT"));
}});
```

Instead, the map **txn** needs to be mapped with values from the properties file. The property file looks like this

```
txn.type=DIV,TFER,PPO
DIV.values=AA,CD,DD,EF
TFER.values=J,TE,EF,RE
PPO.values=PPIN,PPOUT
```

I need the java program to get the values into the Map declaration from the properties file.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value/28370899#28370899](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value/28370899#28370899). It's very close (if not the same) to what you need.

Comment: “Double brace” initialization of Maps or Collections is not advisable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization.