# Spring SpEL - Expression Language to create Map of String and Custom Object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I'm using **Spring Boot** example to read the following from the properties file.

```
sub.region.data={\
    AF: {'subRegionCd' : '34', 'subRegionName' : 'Southern Asia', 'subRegionDesc': '', 'status' : 'A'} \
}
```

I used below, but it doesn't works

```
@Value("#{${sub.region.data}}")
private Map<String, SubRegion> subRegionsMap;
```

SubRegion.java

```
public class SubRegion {
    private String subRegionCd;
    private String subRegionName;
    private String subRegionDesc;
    private String subRegionStatus;
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'com.xxxxxx.model.SubRegion': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:76) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'com.xxxxxx.model.SubRegion': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedMap(TypeConverterDelegate.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:182) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you made a mistake after `'subRegionDesc',`, I think you mean using colon, not a comma here

With spring boot I suggest you to use [ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties), instead of `@Value`.

For example, in this case you have to:

1. put `@EnableConfigurationProperties(SubRegionConfig.class)` to one of your spring configuration class.
2. Create config class:

   ```
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sub.region")
   public static class SubRegionConfig {
       private Map<String, SubRegion> data;
       //getters and setters
   }
   ```
3. Use `.yml` instead of `.properties`, like that:

   ```
   sub:
     region:
      data:
        AF:
         subRegionCd: '34'
         subRegionName: 'Southern Asia'
         subRegionDesc: ''
         subRegionStatus: 'A'
   ```
4. After that you can get every properties you want from `SubRegionConfing`

   ```
   @Autowired
   private SubRegionConfig subRegionConfig;
   ```

`ConfigurationsProperties` is more complex, but more flexible and preferrable to use in most cases.

Comment: Now this gives me : `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap' to required type 'com.XX.model.SubRegion': no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

Comment: spring expects that you are using map inside a map as value, not a java bean (SubRegion)

Comment: If there are multiple SubRegion , how to dynmicaly take them as per the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The **#{}** operator sends data into spEL parser, what means it will try to convert data into its know types, based on spEL syntax as shown [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M5/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-maps) in Spring Docs.

What happens is that the compiler is unable to convert any data into a SubRegion object:

> Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap'
>   to required type 'com.xxxxxx.model.SubRegion': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found

A simple workaround is to nest two Map Objects so you can populate your SubRegion objects after retrieving the values.

```
yourMap={'key1':{'nestedMapKey1:value', 'nestedMapKey2:value2'}}
```

In your .properties file with your code:

```
sub.region.data={'AF':{'subRegionCd':'34', 'subRegionName':'Southern Asia', 'subRegionDesc':'', 'status':'A'}}
```

and then, in your code:

```
    @Value("#{${sub.region.data}}")
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> subRegionsMap;
    // (...) handling the SubRegion
```

My **System.out.println(subRegionMap.get("AF");** outputed:

```
{subRegionCd=34, subRegionName=Southern Asia, subRegionDesc=, status=A}
```