# How do I create a HashMap bean using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to using Spring with Java and I'm trying to instantiate a simple HashMap using Spring's configuration file. I want to know what to put in the Spring config context file to make this work. I know `util:map` is somehow used, but all the example codes I'm seeing are either complex instantiations (e.g. for `HashMap<Class<?>,List<String>>`) from which understanding is difficult, or the author hasn't explained well what he/she has done, leaving me frustrated!

What do I need to put in my beans.xml context file if I want to generate a simple HashMap of this specification ? ...

```
HashMap<Integer, String>
```

Please show a clear example showing the XML and stating any naming assumptions you're making.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348310/how-to-inject-a-mapstring-list-in-java-springs)

Answer (score 7):

I am using Spring 4.0.3, you can use this configuration.You can see the key type of the map is Integer, while the value type is String.

```
<bean id="map" class="java.util.HashMap" scope="prototype" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.Integer" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="1" value="one" />
            <entry key="2" value="two" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

An example of getting this bean is the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    Map<Integer,String> map = (HashMap) context.getBean("map");
    System.out.println(map);
}`
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what the following two lines do, and are they really needed ?: `<entry key="1" value="one" />` `<entry key="2" value="two" />`

Comment: They put initial values into the map, you do not need them.

Comment: It's definitely worth noting that the scope="prototype" is important here as java.util.HashMap is not threadsafe.  This scope will cause a new map to be created for each request for this bean id.  This is necessary because you typically don't want two beans using the same map for thread safety reasons.

Comment: Plus +1 for adding scope="prototype".  This is important, as I explained in my earlier response post.